# how travel between models having same foreign key sql

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, foreign-keys, jinja2

how can I travel dynamically between modals which have same foreign key ?

say i have witers and their posts and their details tables
post and detail table have a fk to writer now my question is can i travel from post to fk writer and then from fk writer to detail table dynamically

```
{{post.writer.detail}
```

is there something of this sort which can be implemented in html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to go about this is to add a property method to model class and access it on your template.

For ex:

```
class Writer(models.Model):
    # some properties
    
    @property
    def get_detail(self):
        # if detail objects does not exist it throws an error
        return Detail.objects.get(writer__id=self.id) 
     

class Detail(models.Model):
    writer = models.ForeignKey(Writer,...)
    # some properties

class Post(models.Model):
    writer = models.ForeignKey(Writer,...)
    # some properties
```

in your template {{post.writer.get_detail}}

The second method : If your FK is unique in detail table , you can also use reverse lookup on your template like this {{post.writer.detail_set.0}}

In case of FK is unique, consider using OneToOneField and you can access detail {{post.writer.detail}}